# Exporting a table while preserving its form

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I am having some slight issues with exporting and importing tables while preserving their forms: A sample code is here:

```
test1[1, 1] = {1, 2, 3};
test1[1, 2] = {4, 5, 6};
test1[3, 1] = {7, 8, 9};
test1[2, 1] = {100, 200, 300};
test1[2, 2] = {400, 500, 600};
test1[3, 2] = {700, 800, 900};
test = Table[test1[l, g], {l, 1, 3}, {g, 1, 2}]
Export["test.dat", test[[All, All]]];
testimport = Import["test.dat"]
```

OUTPUT:

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{100, 200, 300}, {400, 500, 600}}, {{7, 8, 
   9}, {700, 800, 900}}}

{{"{1,", "2,", "3}", "{4,", "5,", "6}"}, {"{100,", "200,", "300}", 
  "{400,", "500,", "600}"}, {"{7,", "8,", "9}", "{700,", "800,", 
  "900}"}}
```

I cannot access the imported file like a regular table. For instance I have the following:

```
In[559]:= testimport[[1, 1]]
test[[1, 1]]

Out[559]= "{1,"
Out[560]= {1, 2, 3}
```

when I want to have `testimport` behave like `test`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `"Package"` as the third argument in both `Export` and `Import`:

```
Export["test.dat", test, "Package"];
testimport = Import["test.dat", "Package"]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{100, 200, 300}, {400, 500, 600}}, {{7, 8,  9}, {700, 800, 900}}}

```
testimport == test
```

> True

See: [this answer by Han Solo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73967/125).

Comment: Thanks @ Han Solo